# Join KStream and GlobalKTable with Avro Object on Join key

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a question regarding key deserialization on KafkaStreams. Specifically I use Kafka Connect and debezium connector to read
data from a Postgres table. Data were imported to a Kafka topic created two Avro schemas on Kafka Schema Registry one for the Key
and one for the Value (this contains all Columns on Table).

I read these data on a GlobalKTable like below:

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);

GlobalKTable<my.namespace.db.Key, my.namespace.db.Value> tableData = builder.globalTable("topic_name");
```

My issue is that I have a topology where I need to join this GlobalKTable with a KStream as the one below:

```
SpecificAvroSerde<EventObj> eventsSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
eventsSpecificAvroSerde.configure(Collections.singletonMap(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
     conf.getString(" kafka.schema.registry.url")), false);

KStream<Integer, EventObj> events = builder.stream( "another_topic_name",Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(),eventsSpecificAvroSerde))
```

Note that the Avro schema for my.namespace.db.Key is

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Key",
  "namespace":"my.namespace.db",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

Obviously the key on GlobalKTable and KStream is a different object and I do not know how to achieve the
join. I initially tried this but it did not work.

```
events.join(tableData,
(key,val) -> {return  my.namespace.db.Key.newBuilder().setId(key).build();}) 
 /* To convert the Integer Key in KStream to the Avro Object Key 
  on GlobalKTable as to achieve the join */
(ev,tData) -> ... );
```

The output I get is the following where I can see a WARN on one of my joined topics (which seems suspect) but there is nothing else no output of the joined entities, it just is as if there is nothing to consume.

```
INFO [Consumer clientId=kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-streams] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336) 
INFO stream-thread [kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor:341) 
WARN [Consumer clientId=kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-streams] The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [my-topic]  (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:241) 
INFO [Consumer clientId=kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-streams] Successfully joined group with generation 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341) 
INFO [Consumer clientId=kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-streams] Setting newly assigned partitions [mip-events-2-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341) 
INFO stream-thread [kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:346) 
INFO KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values: 
    schema.registry.url = [http://kafka-schema-registry:8081]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
 (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig:175) 
INFO KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values: 
    schema.registry.url = [http://kafka-schema-registry:8081]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    specific.avro.reader = true
 (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig:175) 
INFO KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values: 
    schema.registry.url = [http://kafka-schema-registry:8081]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
 (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig:175) 
INFO KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values: 
    schema.registry.url = [http://kafka-schema-registry:8081]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    specific.avro.reader = true
 (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig:175) 
INFO stream-thread [kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 10 ms.
    current active tasks: [0_0]
    current standby tasks: []
    previous active tasks: []
 (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:351) 
INFO stream-thread [kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:346) 
INFO stream-client [kafka-streams-0401c29c-30a9-4969-93f9-5a83b3c834b4]State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams:346)
```

Can I make this join work on Kafka Streams? 
Note that this works if I use a KTable to read the topic and use selectKey on
KStream to convert the key but I want to avoid the repartition.

Or should the right approach be importing my data from database in another way as to avoid creating Avro Objects and 
how is this possible using debezium connectors and KafkaConnect with AvroConverter enable ?

Comment: Not 100% sure -- you should double check the binary format `SpecifAvroSerde` produced for both keys -- for the same key, the binary format must be the same (not an expert on AVRO)...

Comment: You are right to point out SpecificAvroSerde because in the snippet provided I suppressed valuable information trying to give an overview of  the problem, missing related info on how I consume serialized data on the KStream. I 'll edit the post and try to be more clear about the problem I am facing, which seems to be that the Join of the KStream with GlobalKTable does not produce any results unlike the case when I use a KTable for the same topic.

Comment: As you say it works with KTable, I still think it's related to the binary format. The lookup into the KTable/GlobalKTable is done with serializered keys. If the binary format does not match, it won't join. I could imagine, that there are different schema ID uses for KTable/GlobalKTable cases. Can you check the schema IDs that are used? After the selectKey or within the Mapper in the GlobalKTable join, the transformed ID from Integer to Avro will be serialized -- what ID is used there? What ID is used for KTable and GlobalKTable case?

Comment: Ok the puzzling thing is that they have the same schema id. I can see through the kafka-schema-registry-ui that it creates one schema in 
the case of GlobalKTable (changelog) and two others in the case of KTable (repartion based on selectKey and changelog) that all map to 
the same schema id and have the Avro schema shown in the post. Another thing that I have noticed is that if I run the GlobalKTable example first and then the KTable example then the KTable
also does not work ( I use a dockerized environment)

Comment: I see. So it seems not be be a fundamental issue with the GlobalKTable -- no idea where the dependency between both runs come from and why the second run does not work.

Comment: Anyway fortunately I can always settle with a different approach, so thanks for taking the time to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer (and mostly a workaround) but hope it will be useful for someone later on :

Using Avro Keys is usually not recommended, because any change in the format or maybe even in the Avro serialization algorithm may alter the partitioning.

The easy workaround is to use key in string concatenated format : part1#part2, it open up also a lot of optimization techniques based on Kafka Stream Processor API (store.prefixScan(...)).